# Even Odd Separate Average Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, average

```
count = 0
total = 0
amt = int(input("Enter number, type -1 to get average of previous numbers entered "))

while(amt != -1):
    total = total + amt
    count = count + 1
    amt = int(input("Enter number, type -1 to get average of previous numbers entered "))
print("average is " + str(total / count) )
```

This is the code I have so far. I takes all the numbers input and simply finds the average. What I need it to do is separate those input numbers into odds and evens and find the average of those to separate list of inputs. I'm kinda stuck. Help would be amazing. Should mention I'm using Python 3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep track of them separately to begin with, and use a list to automatically keep track of the amount as well, e.g.,

```
evens = []
odds = []

amt = int(input("prompt"))

while (amt != -1):
    if amt % 2 == 0: # even
        evens.append(amt)
    else:
        odds.append(amt)
    amt = int(input("prompt"))

print("odds: " + str(float(sum(odds)) / len(odds)))
print("evens: " + str(float(sum(evens)) / len(evens)))
```

The `len()` and `sum()` functions are your friends.

Comment: When I throw that code into python 3.4.1 I get a invalid syntax?

Comment: I believe it was a paren problem at the end. Try it now.

Comment: I see how you fixed it! Thanks so much. As soon as I can I'll accept the answer